# Is there a name for when a web page only uses web APIs for the data on the screen?

Tags: html, terminology, webapi

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there is a word or term for a web page that exclusively uses web APIs to send and retrieve data instead of posting back to the server and getting an updated view and sending that back to the user. My initial thought was server-less but that's something else entirely, or perhaps just a web app?

Comment: You mean [SPA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA)?

Comment: @David I *believe* OP is referring to ONLY off site data, via API.  Not housing any data on the local server itself.  A SPA can get it's data from anywhere, locally from the browser, offsite via API, or from the server where the application lies (whether by API or straight backend (node, php, python) calls.) -- That said -- I am not aware that there is a specific nomenclature for a site like that.